# Adding a duplicate to a reopened post gives an "invalid request" error

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I just tried to add a duplicate to the existing one. In the meantime, that post got reopened. Since I was still in the dialog, I didn't see that.

When trying to click the *Add button*, this "invalid request" error came up:

> [image]

Can this be replaced for a clear error message please?